# Windows 7 download WordPress and load into LAMP stack and configure

Tags: local-installation, windows

What's the quickest way to create a Windows instance of an existing WordPress site assuming I've got the backup of the code and DB from the server?

I have played around with various LAMP stacks but wonder if there isn't just something simple and light I can do.

Comment: take a look at this http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting/instant-wordpress-development-with-wamp/

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a LAMP on Windows, use a WAMP like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html).

Comment: +100 for XAMPP on Windows. It's quick and easy and self-contained and just works well. I use it for everything.

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is "Linux Apache MySQL PHP".
WAMP is "Windows Apache MySQL PHP".

You will need one of the WAMP packages such as [Wamp Developer](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) (commercial), [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (free), WampServer (free).

Then you'll need to add your previous website files into the DocumentRoot of a VirtualHost and use phpMyAdmin (or the mysql command line) to import your database.

If you change the database name or user or password, you'll also need to edit WP's wp-config.php file and update that info.

Also, WampDeveloper can install WordPress for you automatically, which means you might be able to just import the previous pages/posts/comments if you use the native wordpress export/import abilities (to and from an xml file).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Zend Server Community Edition.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/